# ListPicker Windows Phone 7 exception

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have a problem with the ListPicker component. I download a sample from: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Phone-71-Local-da2fdf80. It is compile, but when I'd like to change page (contains ListPicker), exception was thrown.

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
  Message=Set property 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.ListPicker.ItemCountThreshold' threw an exception. [Line: 42 Position: 63]
  LineNumber=42
  LinePosition=63
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
       at PhoneApp.Views.TaskEditView.InitializeComponent()
       at PhoneApp.Views.TaskEditView..ctor()
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeConstructorInfo rtci, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.Activator.InternalCreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
       at System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.BeginLoad_OnUIThread(AsyncCallback userCallback, PageResourceContentLoaderAsyncResult result)
       at System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginLoad>b__0(Object args)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args)
       at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
       at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(DispatcherPriority priority)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(Object context)
       at System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(Object[] args)
       at System.Windows.Hosting.DelegateWrapper.InternalInvoke(Object[] args)
       at System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(IntPtr pHandle, Int32 nParamCount, ScriptParam[] pParams, ScriptParam& pResult)
  InnerException: System.NotSupportedException
       Message=Cannot set read-only property 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.ListPicker.ItemCountThreshold'.
       StackTrace:
            at MS.Internal.XamlMemberInfo.SetValue(Object target, Object value)
            at MS.Internal.XamlManagedRuntimeRPInvokes.SetValue(XamlTypeToken inType, XamlQualifiedObject& inObj, XamlPropertyToken inProperty, XamlQualifiedObject& inValue)
            at MS.Internal.XcpImports.Application_LoadComponentNative(IntPtr pContext, IntPtr pComponent, UInt32 cUriStringLength, String uriString, UInt32 cXamlStrLength, Byte* pXamlStr, UInt32 cAssemblyStrLength, String assemblyStr)
            at MS.Internal.XcpImports.Application_LoadComponent(IManagedPeerBase componentAsDO, String resourceLocator, UnmanagedMemoryStream stream, UInt32 numBytesToRead, String assemblyString)
            at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
            at PhoneApp.Views.TaskEditView.InitializeComponent()
            at PhoneApp.Views.TaskEditView..ctor()
            at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeConstructorInfo rtci, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
            at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
            at System.Activator.InternalCreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
            at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
            at System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.BeginLoad_OnUIThread(AsyncCallback userCallback, PageResourceContentLoaderAsyncResult result)
            at System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginLoad>b__0(Object args)
            at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
            at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
            at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
            at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args)
            at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
            at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
            at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
            at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(DispatcherPriority priority)
            at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(Object context)
            at System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(Object[] args)
            at System.Windows.Hosting.DelegateWrapper.InternalInvoke(Object[] args)
            at System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(IntPtr pHandle, Int32 nParamCount, ScriptParam[] pParams, ScriptParam& pResult)
```

It is my XAML page:

```
<local:EntityEditPage 
    x:Class="PhoneApp.Views.TaskEditView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PhoneApp.Views"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="696" d:DesignWidth="480"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="edit task" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <ScrollViewer>
                <StackPanel>

                    <!-- title -->
                    <TextBlock Text="Title" Style="{StaticResource DefaultLabelStyle}"  />
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Title, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource FormTextBox}" />

                    <!-- project -->
                    <TextBlock Text="Project" Style="{StaticResource DefaultLabelStyle}"/>
                    <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="listProjects" Style="{StaticResource FormListPicker}">
                        <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Background="Transparent" Margin="12">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" />
                                </Grid>                                
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                        <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                    </toolkit:ListPicker>                    

                    <!-- date -->                    
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Date" Style="{StaticResource DefaultLabelStyle}" />
                            <toolkit:DatePicker x:Name="datePicker" Style="{StaticResource FormDatePicker}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Time" Style="{StaticResource DefaultLabelStyle}" />
                            <toolkit:TimePicker x:Name="timePicker" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>

                    <!-- status -->
                    <TextBlock Text="Status" Style="{StaticResource DefaultLabelStyle}"/>
                    <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="listStatus" ListPickerMode="Normal" SelectedItem="{Binding Status, Mode=TwoWay}">
                        <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                    </toolkit:ListPicker>

                    <!-- description -->
                    <TextBlock Text="Description" Style="{StaticResource DefaultLabelStyle}"  />
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Description, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="285" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" Style="{StaticResource FormTextBox}" />

                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

    <!--Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar-->
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar>            
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/icons/appbar.check.rest.png" Text="button" Click="OnOK"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/icons/appbar.cancel.rest.png" Text="button" Click="OnCancel"/>
       </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>

</local:EntityEditPage>
```

Comment: How many items are you adding? And why are you setting the ListPickerMode? I believe that's the default

Comment: @willmel I added new items from local database. I is not my code. I simply copy and paste source from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Phone-71-Local-da2fdf80. If you could you can download this sample and help me with this problem, as I don't know why it's not work;/